# C# Application Blocks - Static Class and methods

Tags: vb.net

I have developed a Data Access Layer for an application that connects to Oracle and SQL databases.  I have written a similar class to that provided by Application Blocks here: http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html.

I am not sure why the methods are static in the link.  When I want to perform a CRUD operation I create an instance of the class and then call the appropriate function.  Why are the methods static?

VB.NET does not allow for Shared classes (only shared functions).  Therefore I was thinking about making all the functions Shared.  Before I do this I want to understand why the methods in the link are static.

I have researched this.  For example, the following link explains that the methods are static but does not explain why: https://web.archive.org/web/20210304123854/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062503-1.aspx.

Comment: because..microsoft built a really good o-o language in c#, but their developer core are from a procedural language background - so you end up with procedural-style written APIs. what you have here is a set of re-usable methods that do not require an instance of an object to execute.

Comment: @jenson-button-event, thanks.  Are you saying that it would be better design to have this class as none static?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of big reasons spring to mind.

- Simplicity

Everything you need to run that method arrives via the parameter list.  Developers don't have to follow any quirks of an instantiated implementation.

- Speed.

According to the following link, static method calls are about 4-5 times faster than their instanced equivalent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In vb a module behaves as a static class does in c#. Useful when you just want a helper type class with all shared methods.

As a very general rule static/shared methods should be more efficient. As you do not need to instantiate a class to make the same call.  So you aren't generating an entire object to do something that you don't need a full object to do.  For example, a simple math function.

```
public shared function AddNumbers(number1 as integer, number2 as integer) as integer
```

versus something that modifies or accesses object data.

```
public function AccrueInterest() as integer
```

which might be something that accesses an interestRate and Balance property on the same object.